# How can I make my HTML update when I press the update button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
   function setTodoInfo(id) {

      let todoInfo = todoInfoRef.current.value
      if(todoInfo === "") return
     todo.info = todoInfo
      todoInfoRef.current.value = null

    }


  <>
   <h1 className="delete-button"> hi, {todo.info} </h1>
   <form>
   <input type="text" ref={todoInfoRef}/>
   </form>
  <button onClick={closeInfo} className="delete-button" > Close </button>
   <button onClick={setTodoInfo}> Set Info</button>
   </>
```

When I click the set Info button its updating the info property on the todo, but it doesn't display it when you click, you have to close it and reopen it to see the updated info

Comment: You're lacking some basic knowledge which you can find in React docs. Also the code you posted is not enough to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

react uses reference to be able to see it should or not rerender. using refs means the reference doesnt change...

as pointed, you should really see the docs on how to make it the "react way"

if you really need to make with references, then you could add some "render" function.

put in a `useState` a integer or something else, then call `setState` to change its value... that should force a render.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function useForceUpdate(){
     const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // integer state
     return () => setValue(value => value + 1); // update the state to force 

 }



  (inside functional component)
   const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
 call forceUpdate where needed
```